# How to organize appition with PostgreSQL and php?

Tags: php, postgresql

I watched Yii2 and Laravel but I do not want use ActiveRecord, ORM and QueryBuilder for my application but if I do not use them that 50% functionality framework you can trash. I want to use (cte, over, transations, stored procedure and big query) also I would like to use unit test.

Could you tell me how I can organize structure this application on php, may be use patterns Table Gateway and Table Module for split layer SQL code and php?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I've always found it simpler to just use PDO and SQL.  I usually find myself fighting the frameworks, especially with cte and stored procedures.  Postgresql has great support for json, so it makes it very easy to fetch objects and even complex, nested objects with a single statement.  For instance...

```
$sql = "select row_to_json(g) from (
    select
        firstname,
        lastname,
        (select json_agg(e) from (
             select address from email where fk_user=user.id
          )e
        ) as emails
    from user
    where id=:id
)g;"
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('id', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$obj = json_decode($stmt->fetchColumn(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have started the Pomm Project for that purpose: leverage Postgres features from PHP. Here is a complete example calculating the Fibonacci sequence:

```
<?php

//composer
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pomm = new PommProject\Foundation\Pomm(
    ['my_db' => ['dsn' => 'pgsql://user:password@host/db_name']]
    );

$sql = <<<SQL
WITH RECURSIVE
  fibonacci AS (
    SELECT 0::int4 as n, 1::int4 as m, 1::int4 as level
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      parent.m as n,
      parent.n + parent.m as m,
      parent.level + 1 as level
    FROM fibonacci AS parent
    WHERE level < $*::int4
    )
SELECT n, m, level FROM fibonacci
SQL;
$iterator = $pomm['my_db']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query($sql, [20]) // pass 20 as max level to recurse
    ;

if (!$iterator->isEmpty()) {
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
        printf("Level = %d (%d, %d).\n", $row['level'], $row['n'], $row['m']);
    }
} else {
    printf("The query returned no results.\n");
}
```

The returned results are converted into PHP equivalent types (ie, booleans in postgres are booleans in PHP, same for Datetime, DateInterval etc.) and it supports almost all PostgreSQL types (tstzrange, json, circle, point, HStore, inet etc…).

For more complex projects, Pomm also proposes an optional Object Model Manager that comes with pre defined queries (CRUD).It is possible (and advised) to add more complex queries (SQL joins) into dedicated methods in each entity class.

```
$model = $pomm['my_db']->getModel(CustomerModel::class);
$customer = $model
    ->findByPk(['customer_id' => $http_query['customer_id']])
    ;
$customer['email'] = $http_query['email']; // trigger setEmail() method
$model->updateOne($customer, ['email']);   // update the email field only
```

It is a projection oriented model manager, which means it makes the fields in the SELECT part of each entity configurable. It is possible to enrich the SELECT with computed fields using all Postgres functions or to remove fields for all entity related SQL queries.

There is a bundle for integration with Symfony2, Silex and Zend Framework.